# When Android use msf: after select a file

Tags: android, android-storage, android-document-provider

I have an app to select a file from storage. My app crashed cause of old library not updated for years. I found the problem that when android returns a uri like "content://...." sometimes it have "msf:", example like: 'content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/msf:24'.

In what condition android returns "msf:"?

Comment: Your app should not care about any specific characters in a `Uri`. Use `ContentResolver` and `openInputStream()` to get an `InputStream` to be able to read the content identified by the `Uri`.

Answer (score 0):

When the user directly chooses a file from Download collection instead of first browsing to storage, then to Download directory and finally picking a file.

I do not see that collection anymore on modern systems.

But your app only crashes if you do nasty things like trying to get 'a real path from uri' and or not checking for a null path and not catching a NullPointerException.